# Screen APP - Using a Cellular as a screen

Tags: screen

Is possible to use an regular cellular as a screen by conneting an usb/hdmi cable. would exist an APP which could identify and turns the cell in a raspberry pi screen?

Comment: By saying App, you mean a smartphone?

Comment: yep, sorry for missing this information!

Comment: It's going to be complicated to use a phone as a monitor with a Pi. You'll have a *much* easier time just setting up a VNC app for GUI work, and an SSH app for terminal work.